# CFolderDialog SetStatusText

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, modal-dialog, directory

I have a CFolderDialog and I want to set some text for it. I've tried derivating another class from it and set the text at initialization but it does not seem to work. Here's the sample:

```
class BackupLocationDialog : public CFolderDialog
{
public:
    void BackupLocationDialog::OnInitialized()
    {
        BackupLocationDialog::SetStatusText(_T("A HORSE"));
    }
};
```

Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas ?

Comment: "it doesn't seem to work" is very little to go on. Can you describe what happens?

Comment: No status is set at all. That's about it :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is good example [***CFolderDialog - Selecting Folders***](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/cfolderdialog.aspx?display=Print), you can find here how to set text. Just download [***Source code***](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/cfolderdialog/FolderDlg_Src.zip) open FolderDlg.cpp and I hope you will find answer.

Pay attention on this part of code in FolderDlg.cpp file:

```
VOID CFolderDialog::SetStatusText( IN LPCTSTR pszText )
{
    ASSERT( m_hWnd != NULL );

    ::SendMessage( 
        m_hWnd, BFFM_SETSTATUSTEXT, 
        (WPARAM)0, (LPARAM)pszText
    );
}
```

Comment: Think I've tried that sample before :P I'll do it again and let you know how it ends up in a sec.

Comment: Hmm I finally managed. Just used BIF_STATUSTEXT on init and then f.m_bi.lpszTitle = _T("GasLampKiller"); and it works fine now. Thanks for your help though, i'll award you the bounty when the 24 hours timer ends.

Comment: Oh, I jsut noticed your sample now. That's helpful aswell :P

Answer (score 0):

you may want to check out this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163789.aspx

...

FolderPick derives a new class, CMyFolderDialog, with overrides for OnInitialized and OnValidateFailed. When the dialog is initialized, FolderPick sets the status text and changes the name of the OK button to "Choose Me!"

```
void CMyFolderDialog::OnInitialized()
{
   SetStatusText(_T("Nice day, isn't it?"));
   SetOKText(L"Choose Me!");
}
```

There are a couple of things to underscore here. First, CFolderDialog has wrappers like SetStatusText and SetOKText for folder dialog messages like BFFM_SETSTATUSTEXT and BFFM_SETOKTEXT.

If you were programming in C, you'd call ::SendMessage; with CFolderDialog you just call the wrappers. The only caveat is that you can only call these wrappers from within your virtual notification handlers (OnInitialized, OnSelChanged, and the rest) because m_hWnd is valid only while the folder dialog is actually running, not before or after calling BrowseForFolder.

Internally, CFolderDialog subclasses the folder dialog the first time its callback receives a notification. The second thing to notice is that some BFFM_ messages require Unicode strings, not LPCTSTRs. That's why "Choose Me!" in the snippet is a wide character string (prefixed with L).

The Microsoft documentation has a couple of minor errors I should point out in case you try to program SHBrowseForFolder in C. The documentation says to pass the string for BFFM_SETOKTEXT in WPARAM; actually, it's LPARAM. It also says that BFFM_SETSELECTION requires a Unicode string, but BFFM_SETSELECTION is available in both A and W flavors, so you can use LPCTSTR.

Comment: If you look closely to my sample that's exactly what I did.